# EF4: Loading navigation properties using SP

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, relationship

I can only use SPs to load my entities from database. I can successfully load customer by using import function:

```
Customer cust = context.GetCustomerById(customerId);
```

Then I need to load cust.Orders collection using another SP:

```
IEnumerable<Order> cust_orders = context.GetOrdersByCustomerId(customerId);
```

I get list of related orders which have property Customer correctly set to the already loaded Customer instance. The problem arises when I try to do something like:

```
foreach(Order ord in cust.Orders)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ord.Number); // "SELECT permission required ..." exception is thrown here
}
```

Is there a way to Load Orders property without triggering Select?

Comment: What kind of entities are you using? `EntityObject` or POCO? ObjectContext API or DbCotnext API?

Comment: EntityObject and ObjectContext database-first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable LazyLoading and load Orders through appropriate SP call, like this:

```
DBContext.DataBase.SqlQuery<Order>("exec spGetOrders {0}", invoiceID).ToList();
```

Comment: How do I do 'loading Orders through appropriate SP call' so that I'll be able to do foreach as in example. I can load Orders now using import function but they don't show up in the cust.Orders collection.

Comment: Anyone? It's impossible that our company is the only one restricting data access through SPs and if EF can do relationship fixup in one direction why wouldn't it be possible to do in another, meaning populate collection with read child entities. It must be possible since DataExtensions framework from MS provide method Bind which seems to be doing what I'm after.